# SQL Express 2008 R2 Server Management Studio duplicate toolbars

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've installed SQL Express 2008 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine and have noticed that the Server Management Studio has duplicate toolbars, so that the standard toolbar shows, "File File Edit Edit" etc. The content of the toolbars is duplicated in a similar way. Has anyone else noticed similar issues?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It should probably be moved to superuser or serverfault

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently as well.  When I went to add/remove buttons, and for each button, one was enabled and one was disabled.

Once I removed all of the enabled ones, the disabled ones were all that was left, and it went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS saves information about toolbar settings in .prf files.
Try to locate them in folder with path, similar to:

C:\Users\LOGINNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell

and delete .prf file with latest modification date. This will force SSMS to re-create all buttons/menues.